# Process.Start cannot find the executable

Tags: c#, .net, process.start

I want to change the BCD from my .NET application. To do so, I've created this little snippet:

```
static void RunBcdEdit() 
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\Windows\\System32\\bcdedit.exe";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;        
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

The strange thing is that it throws an exception saying that

> the system cannot find the file especified

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Whelp, sounds like c:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe  is sometimes inaccesible?

Comment: System32 is a very 'odd' directory. If you have a 32-bit app trying to access it, it is redirected to \windows\syswow64. This may be what is tripping you up.

Comment: Project > Properties > Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  You don't prefer it.  Learn more about the File System Redirector that is used on a 64-bit OS to keep 32-bit apps compatible from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

Comment: So, what's the best approach to interact with BCDEdit? Or to modify the BCD?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced similar issues with running applications out of System32. A workaround I found was using SysNative. In testing there was no consistency when System32 would work or when SysNative would work for different applications that reside in System32.

```
static void RunBcdEdit() 
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\Windows\\SysNative\\bcdedit.exe";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;        
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Does it work for x86 systems, too? I mean, should I change the path depending on the system architecture?

Comment: @SuperJMN I'm not sure about x86 systems, I've only used it on x64, so you'll have to try it out and see.